# Allow pipeline execution only from AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline

Is there a way to deny start execution of CodePipeline from any external sources (CLI command, API requests etc.) and only allow it from AWS console via "Release changes"?

Comment: I would not recommend this but you can investigate the policy variable [aws:UserAgent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-useragent).

Comment: @jarmod how exactly can the `aws:UserAgent` be used for this?

Comment: @MarkB it is possible as illustrated by my answer

Comment: I think the bigger question is why should anyone care if the pipeline is triggered by that button, versus someone running an API call that does exactly the same thing that button does?

Comment: @MarkB well, saying it can't be done is not the same as questioning whether it should be done or not. you should delete your comment

Comment: @MarkB Because of audit purposes. This is extremely sensitive pipeline and only specific subset of users in a controlled environment should be able to trigger

Comment: @jarmod I was thinking of using something like request properties, but pipeline doesn't have a resource policy (e.g. like S3) how do use them?

Comment: @Paolo I was simply proposing that policies can be written to assert the presence of  specific user agent strings in the API request. The OP could investigate whether or not such a policy is helpful. I don't know if the AWS console forwards the user agent string to the eventual AWS API request. Suspect not, tbh. AWS SDKs and the awscli may inject certain user agent strings that could be denied, for example. Certainly would not be perfect, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of achieving this is if you create a user with *only* AWS console access, and then make it so only that user has the permissions to execute that action by giving the user the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "codepipeline:StartPipelineExecution",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

(replace `Account` and `UserName` with the account ID and the username of the user you created).

This assumes that you are managing the AWS account and that you have implemented a policy of least-privilege access throughout, meaning that no other IAM role or IAM user has the codepipeline permission in question.

Comment: @MarkB obviously the assumption is that OP is in charge of the AWS account

Comment: @MarkB well, the OP hasn't given enough information on that. the assumption is that least-priviledge access is being used throughout the account, meaning that there are no IAM roles or users with programmatic access that have the codepipeline permission

Comment: @MarkB I've added that assumption to the answer